# Database Design of a booking system with pre-existing availability constraints

Tags: database, database-design

I am working on a booking system for parking spots using rails. Here are the interesting tables and columns of my database schema for this problem.(I did not include the user table, as the only relevant column is the id column).

```
`ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140430100754) do

  create_table "bookings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "spot_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "begins_at"
    t.datetime "ends_at"
  end

  create_table "parkings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "owner_id"
    t.string   "address"
  end

  create_table "spots", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "parking_id"
    t.string   "number"
  end

end`
```

At the beginning the booking system was simple: A user would book a spot with a start time and an end time, and when querying for available spots, I would take the existing bookings into account.

However, I now have to add availabilities on each spot: The owner of one parking spot must be able to set for each day of the week when his/her spot is available. I have done some research on how to store this in the database, but I did not find anything approaching. (Only simple booking systems like my previous system)

Here are the main issues I have to address:

- The granularity of the booking system must be of 15 minutes at least
- I have to query very often the database to find all the parkings that still have at least one available spot for a given timeframe.

**My first question is about the way to store the initial availability infos.**

The only solution I could think of is storing it using booleans for each 15 minutes timeframe (with that for seven days, it is 672 columns, does not seem a groundbreaking idea to me). So do you have any advice on how to store this, and how to query this in an efficient way to check availability ?

**My second question is about the booking table:**

I want to clean the booking table in order not to let it grow, (I'm afraid it will slow down the queries to check availability on spots and parkings) BUT keep track of the previous booking by storing it in another table (which I won't query very often). Is it a good approach or not ?

**Notes**

I stated I'm using Ruby on rails, but I think the issue is language independent, and much more a database design issue.